# Jquery UI Autocomplete appends to body rather than the given object in JQ UI Version 1.8.6

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Ive been using jquery auto-completes on my web page for a while , but after updating jquery ui to version 1.8.6 from 1.8rc3 , the autocomplete ul object is now appended to the body rather than directly after the given selector.

The code below is not valid of course, it just highlights the problem im having.

**In 1.8rc3**

```
   $("#myinput").autocomplete(.....

   <input id="myinput"/> 
   <ul id="autocomplete"></ul>
   <div>Loads of other content</div>
   <div>Loads of other content</div>
   <div>Loads of other content</div>
   </body>
```

**In 1.8.6**

```
   $("#myinput").autocomplete(.....

   <input id="myinput"/> 
   <div>Loads of other content</div>
   <div>Loads of other content</div>
   <div>Loads of other content</div>
   <ul id="autocomplete"></ul>   
   </body>
```

**So my question is, is there a way to make the autocomplete append after my given selector rather than appending to the body?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use option "appendTo"

```
$("#input").autocomplete({
    appendTo: $("#input").next()
});
```

But this can only append to some container as you suspect. If you want to be able to append autocomplete right after your input then you have to tweak the autocomplete source directly (change appendTo() for after())

Comment: you sure you can use this? its not listed in the documentation for the options http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#options

Comment: great thankyou very much, this works as my autocomplete was in a td i was able to use appendTo: $("#input").parent()

Comment: I don't know why this option is not listed in documentation, but if you take a look at the source code, you will see this option as the first one ... happy to help :)

Comment: It's part of the documentation I looked at. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo

Answer (score 5):

The original answer helped me to track down an easier solution.

My situation was a little different: I was trying to get a custom autocomplete working in a (Bootstrap) modal. Also, I was using a newer version of jquery-ui (1.11.4). Hopefully my answer will add value to anybody that gets to this posting.

According to [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo) for option **appendTo**:

> When the value is null, the parents of the input field will be checked
>   for a class of ui-front. If an element with the ui-front class is
>   found, the menu will be appended to that element.

By adding a class **ui-front** to a parent element (in my case, the modal), I was able to bring the drop-down-list from behind the scenes and into the modal.

So you could wrap your input in a container and add to the container the class **ui-front**.

Comment: I'm working on a project using both jquery ui and bootstrap (don't ask!) and ui-front saved my bacon!